# Spring boot security fails after moving server to new host

Tags: vaadin14, mariadb-10.3, spring-boot-security

Old configuration:

- MariaDB server on remote host A
- Tomcat application served from host B

New configuration

- MariaDB server and Tomcat application served on host C

The old configuration worked fine using Spring security pulling BCrypt password from database on host A.

I made adjustments to the app to point to host C and it runs fine from the IDE using only host C for all requirements.

When I put the .war on host C the application runs fine but will not authenticate yielding:

```
Incorrect username or password
Check that you have entered the correct username and password and try again.
```

The username and password are the same in both cases.

I would have expected issues when running the app from the IDE if I had mis-configured the server (firewall, database user and rights, etc.) but that works fine.

I also would have expected the production case to be much easier as the app and database are on the same server.

The only final detail is that the password is held in a Joomla database as a BCrypt field. I moved that database to server C.

I find this difficult to debug given that it works fine from the IDE yet fails in production. Spring security is a bit opaque to me as well.

Any help very much appreciated!!